# Store and update multiple values in a single cookie

Tags: php, cookies

How can I store multiple values in a **single cookie** and keep adding more values in the same cookie.

For example:

If a user_id 1 votes a post_id 1, i want to store (1, 1) in the cookie.

If the user_id 1 votes a post_id 2, I want to update the same cookie with values (1,2).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

use json to store array in single cookie

**set cookie:**

```
setcookie("myCookie", json_encode(array(1, 2)));
```

**get cookie:**

```
print_r(json_encode($_COOKIE["myCookie"]));
```